# Python Upper function

Tags: python, pandas, uppercase

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"email": "test@gmail.com"}])
is_upper = lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x
df = df.applymap(trim_strings)
a = df.to_dict("records")
```

The response I get :

```
[{'email': 'test@gmail.com'}]
```

The response I expected :

```
[{'email': 'TEST@GMAIL.COM'}]
```

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected output, consider try this:

```py
df['email'] = df['email'].str.upper()
```

Your `df`:

```
    email
0   TEST@GMAIL.COM
```

to get the dictionary:

```py
foo_dict = df.to_dict()
foo_dict
```

```
{'email': {0: 'TEST@GMAIL.COM'}}
```

Block Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"email": "test@gmail.com"}])
df['email'] = df['email'].str.upper()
foo_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. If I need to apply `str.upper()` to all the columns have value string, what can be the solution?

Comment: Hi  
@Aman Raheja.   Consider flag the post as the answer.  It encourage all community to help you lot faster.   After, consider creating a new post with your new problem.  All community will help you better this way :)